# Return variable from python module

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-module

I don't know how to get the variables a and b in my main program where i imported a module.

scipt1.py:

```
def med():

    import math
    n=int(input("n: \n"))
    x=float(input("media: \n"))
    s2=float(input("s2: \n"))
    t=float(input("t_{a/2, n-1}: \n"))

    a=x-(t*math.sqrt(s2/n))

    b=x+(t*math.sqrt(s2/n))
    return a,b
```

in scipt2.py:

```
from script1 import med

med()

#for example I want to do
x = a - 1000
y = b + 1000
```

but I get: *"NameError: name 'a' is not defined"* although I can input the values of the variables n,x,t,s2. 
What I am doing wrong?

Comment: That isn't how `return` works... you do not *return variables* you return *an object*.

Comment: Learn python.  Read a tutorial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from script1 import med

a,b = med() #store the values that your function returns

#for example I want to do
x = a - 1000
y = b + 1000
```